# Learn Python the Hard Way - Exercise 43 - TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python

I typed in this code from [LPTHW Exercise 43](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html). It seems identical to the exercise. I have checked to make sure that I did not mix up spaces and tabs. (I used tabs).

I get the following error when I try to run it.

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

When I copy and paste the code from the lesson it runs fine. I did a text comparison of the two files and could not find a difference.

```
class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class Engine(object):

    def _init_(self, scene_map):
        pass

    def play(self):
        pass

class Death(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class EscapePod(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class Map(object):

    def _init_(self, start_scene):
        pass

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        pass

    def opening_scene(self):
        pass


a_map = Map('central corridor')

a_game = Engine(a_map)

a_game.play()enter code here
```

Comment: `'_init_' != '__init__'`

Comment: use 2 underscores for init "__init__" and not "_init_"

Answer (score 4):

It is `__init__` with two underscore characters!